# How to compare two rows of a column and then alter another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to be able to look at two rows that have the same identification number, then compare the number of children for each person and assign the larger number for both people. I was thinking of grouping by (.groupby) ID number, but I am not sure where to go from there. Specifically I am not sure how to check which numchild is larger while also replacing the smaller number with the larger one. For example:

```
 Index   ID             NumChil  
 0       2011000070          3   
 1       2011000070          0   
 2       2011000074          0 
 3       2011000074          1
```

should turn in to:

```
 Index   ID             NumChil  
 0       2011000070          3   
 1       2011000070          3   
 2       2011000074          1 
 3       2011000074          1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preferred Option**
You want to use `groupby` with `transform` and `max`

```
df.groupby('ID').NumChil.transform('max')

0    3
1    3
2    1
3    1
Name: NumChil, dtype: int64
```

---

You can assign back inplace with

```
df['NumChil'] = df.groupby('ID').NumChil.transform('max')
df

   Index          ID  NumChil
0      0  2011000070        3
1      1  2011000070        3
2      2  2011000074        1
3      3  2011000074        1
```

Or produce a copy with

```
df.assign(NumChil=df.groupby('ID').NumChil.transform('max'))

   Index          ID  NumChil
0      0  2011000070        3
1      1  2011000070        3
2      2  2011000074        1
3      3  2011000074        1
```

---

**Alternative Approaches**

**`groupby` with `max` and `map`**

```
df.ID.map(df.groupby('ID').NumChil.max())

0    3
1    3
2    1
3    1
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

---

```
df.assign(NumChil=df.ID.map(df.groupby('ID').NumChil.max()))

   Index          ID  NumChil
0      0  2011000070        3
1      1  2011000070        3
2      2  2011000074        1
3      3  2011000074        1
```

**`groupby` with `max` and `join`**

```
df.drop('NumChil', 1).join(df.groupby('ID').NumChil.max(), on='ID')

   Index          ID  NumChil
0      0  2011000070        3
1      1  2011000070        3
2      2  2011000074        1
3      3  2011000074        1
```